# Sticky footer inside other divs

Tags: javascript, css, footer, sticky-footer

I have a given HTML structure, and can't really manage to change it to put the footer along a wrapper div and nothing else, so the "classic" sticky footer code doesn't work. The structure is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <sidebar></sidebar>
        <maincontent>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <footer></footer>
        </maincontent>
    </div>
</body>
```

The footer has to be there in order for the sidebar to appear and disappear correctly through js, if I put it where it works with the sticky footer code the sidebar appears over it, and the main content doesn't extend to the end of the page.

Any way to make the footer sticky other than change everything?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the footer stick to the maincontent then try this

```
#maincontent-selector {
    position: relative;
}

#footer-selector {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Your parent element should have position relative or absolute to make the  footer stick to the parent bottom.

Else it will stick to the page's bottom.